# difference between the content of two files

Tags: diff, unix

I have two files one file subset of other and i want to obtain a file which has contents not common to both.for example

**File1**

```
apple
mango
banana
orange
jackfruit
cherry
grapes
eggplant
okra
cabbage
```

**File2**

```
apple
banana
cherry
eggplant
cabbage
```

The resultant file, difference of above two files

```
mango
orange
jackfruit
grapes
okra
```

Any ideas on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use awk, no sorting necessary (reduce overheads)

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{f[$1];next}(!($1 in f)) ' file2 file
mango
orange
jackfruit
grapes
okra
```

Answer (score 11):

You can sort the files then use `comm`:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
grapes
jackfruit
mango
okra
orange
```

You might also want to use `comm -3` instead of `comm -23`:

```
  -1              suppress lines unique to FILE1
  -2              suppress lines unique to FILE2
  -3              suppress lines that appear in both files
```

Comment: +1 Awesome. I solved this from scratch a few times in the past few years and loved this built-in solution because I won't need to carry a script around now. Can be simplified further if the files are presorted to remove the <( ... ) syntax to avoid confusing newbies

Answer (score 3):

**1 Only one instance , in either**

- cat File1 File2 | sort | uniq -u

**2 Only in first file**

- cat File1 File2 File2 | sort | uniq -u

**3 Only in second file**

- cat File1 File1 File2 | sort | uniq -u

Comment: This is very clever!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Files uncommon to both files**

```
diff --changed-group-format="%<" --unchanged-group-format="%>" file1 file2
```

**2. File unique to first file**

```
diff --changed-group-format="%<" --unchanged-group-format="" file1 file2
```

**3. File unique to second file**

```
diff --changed-group-format="" --unchanged-group-format="%>" file1 file2
```

Hope it works for you