# Deleting a pattern from a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files:

File1:

```
ABC123
XYZ123
```

File2:

```
ABC123,APPLE
ABC123,BALL
XYZ123,BAT
ABC123,CAT
HJK456,MAT
```

I want to remove all the patterns in File2, which are there in File1. Meaning I want to removed ABC123 and XYZ123 from File2. For doing this I am running the below script.

```
        while read -r line
        do
        sed -i "/$line/d" $File2
        done<File1
```

With this script the File2 will have

```
HJK456,MAT
```

This script is serving my purpose, but I want to do this where File1 has 100 000 entries and File2 has 500 000 entries. I know the sed is slow here. Can anyone help me to get some command which will do this job and its faster.

Comment: "1 lakh"?  What is that?

Comment: @Droppy: 'lakh' is the indian currency equivalent for 100,00 :)

Comment: First time I've heard a currency used to describe the number of lines in a file before...

Comment: @Droppy : It's not a currency, simply a metric like million!

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please search before asking questions

Comment: I did not find any script which is faster, in my search. Thats the reason for asking this question.

Comment: look in the grep man page.

Comment: I mean there are 1,00,000 entries in File1 and 5,00,000 entries in File2.

Comment: but grep will be slower than sed right?

Comment: @Programmer what would make you think that? And I don't think anything is slower than running processes for each line in a read while loop.

Comment: My experience is that sed, awk & grep are the fastest you can use. If you are finding performance problems, I would try rethinking the while loop, but I don`t see an obvious answer.

Comment: tr command can help? Yes as you said, thinking of while loop itself. Next I am thinking of splitting the file into multiple files and running the commands.

Comment: `grep -vf file file2`

Comment: Might get bashed for this, but just going to try it! bash `join` and `sort` could help, but am not sure of the performance metrics for it. Can you try grep `join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2 | cut -d ',' -f 1)` file2. It is actually grep followed by `  join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2 | cut -d ',' -f 1)` file2 ` and file2

Comment: @123's:- suggestion is more elegant than mine

Comment: @123- Thanks for the solution. I think this will serve my purpose. Have kept for execution now.

Comment: @Inian - Thanks for your reply as well.

Comment: @123 You should post that as an answer so that Programmer can accept it and mark this question as answered.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan You can post it if you want, it already exists on the site though. This should have been closed as a dupe, but i honestly can't be bothered looking for the other one.

Comment: @123 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832988/difference-between-the-content-of-two-files is the best I could find but it's not an exact duplicate and your answer is more elegant than any of those. I'd suggest that Inian post an answer given he/she put so much effort into it already.

Comment: I did grep -Fvf file file2, which is much faster compared to grep -vf file file2